# Values in a CSV file not reading into a two-dimensional array properly in C

Tags: arrays, c, file

I have a text file that contains numbers like below:

```
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
23,10,5,7,8,9,10,1,2,5
```

I am trying to read all those values into a two-dimensional array using the C programming language. The first line reads into the array successfully, but the rest of the values are 0s.

How can I debug where the problem is?

Below is the code I am using:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //create a new file pointer
    FILE* myfile = fopen("matrixA.csv", "r");
    //define the dimensions of our multidimensional array
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLS = 10;
    //allocate memory to our array
    int array[ROWS][COLS];
    //intialize all members of the array to zero
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
    //check if the file is null
    if (myfile == NULL) {
        printf("%s", "The file does not exist");
        //return an exit code to the operating system
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    //the file is real, read from it and enter its values into the matrix
    //array
    for (int row = 0;row < ROWS;row++) {
        for (int col = 0;col < COLS;col++) {
            if (fscanf(myfile,"%d,", &array[row][col]) != 1) {
                //return an exit code to the operating system
                printf("%s\n", "The scan of some components of this file was unsuccessful");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        //for every member of this array, print them out
        for (int i = 0;i < ROWS;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < COLS;j++) {
                printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
            }
            //break a row when a row is complete
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting when I run my code on the terminal is like below after printing out the elements of the array which is incorrect.

```
23 10 5 7 8 9 10 1 2 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I make my code read all the values of the file into the two-dimensional array successfully?

Comment: @SparKot, okay wil try that idea

Comment: Why do you have a loop when you put an unconditional `return` inside the loop? When you think about that, you may understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: @HAL9000 I thought it was a typo ;-)

Comment: @HAL9000, am returning an exit_failure code if the fscanf function returns 0 which is a false and means the read process from the file into the index of the array failed

Comment: Move the print code out of the `for (int row` loop.

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius, I am not talking about the error checking, but the lone `return 0` at the end of the loop body of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please close your file.
Secondly, the fscanf() does not read consecutive lines as expected. Finding more information in this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-VN/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/fscanf-does-not-read-consecutive-line

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you've moved output statements into reading loops. Moving them out should fix it.

```c
    //the file is real, read from it and enter its values into the matrix
    //array
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            if (fscanf (myfile, "%d,", &array[row][col]) != 1) {
                //return an exit code to the operating system
                printf ("%s\n", "The scan of some components of this file was unsuccessful");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
    //for every member of this array, print them out
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf ("%d ", array[i][j]);
        //break a row when a row is complete
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

Also, you're mixing C++ with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>

//#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;
```

There is no need to `memset()`

```
//memset (array, 0, sizeof (array));
```

As already pointed out, it's better to read the whole line from input file and extract matrix elements from it. This gives you more control to validate input file for erroneous data.

- there was text data instead of numbers
- insufficient/excess columns/fields specified on a line

Comment: C and C++ can be typed on the same editor and it works because the later is an improvement of the earlier?